# Conditioning for automotive electronics

Tags: automotive, protection, signal-integrity

I have a simple application: convert an automotive throttle 0-5V line to 0-2.5V on a circuit near (and feeding into) a fan controller. Very loose maximum frequency is 10Hz. I reduced R1 because the SA5.0A is potentially very leaky, but even with worst-case leak only 1% of Vin will be lost.

These component choices are largely because they're what I have on hand. I'm open to hearing more appropriate substitutes. One question mark will be maximum current required from the op-amp because I don't yet know what the input impedance of the fan controller is, so I'll have to measure that.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flQbWO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Are there any typical automotive safety measures I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SA's can handle 500 W transients.  Whoa!  Change R1 to 100k, change C1 to 0.1 uF high-quality*, change both SA's to boring old 1N4148's (yes, non-Zener, you don't need the Zenerissitude), the op-amp now has 100k in series with it and will be fine) and call it a day.  If you really require the high accuracy you describe, make sure the 0.1 uF is high-quality, very low leakage etc.  You see I kept your R1-C1 time constant the same, but now the load and components are much more suited.  The op-amp input is < 1 pA (yes pico-ampere) so it is very high-impedance.

Comment: Why the change to 100k? Because a bigger resistor will offer more protection?

Comment: And why is the 1N4148 better? Probably because it leaks less?

Comment: Larger resistor presents smaller "load" to the automotive circuit.  E.g. if the automotive circuit presents (as you say) 0 thru 2.5V, then your 100Ω resistor could load it by 2.5/100 = 25 mA.  Do you know the output impedance of the sensor?  That current will be drawn for an instant when the capacitor is not-yet-charged.  OTOH 100kΩ would load maximum 25µA which is VERY small.  And this allows the capacitor to be much smaller in value, too, which is better as 100µF is a bit large for an automotive-ready (heat resistant, longevity etc) part whereas a smaller cap would be easier to find. -cont'd

Comment: As for the 1n4148, it has maximum capacitance of 4pF vs your SAs which are 100's of pF, and more-importantly are totally widely available (might be most popular diode ever for sale) and are cheap.  I guess what I'm leaning toward is that it's "easier" to block tiny transients (such as those flowing thru 10k or 100k) with common cheap diodes than it is with "large" transients (such as flowing thru 100Ω).  Because you're just driving an op-amp input anyway, you don't need anything super-low-impedance, and you don't want to load the automotive circuit with high current draws if you don't need to

Comment: ^ ^ correction to above, my bad, you said the auto circuit will drive 0-5V hence 100Ω is 50mA current draw.

Comment: And the capacitance of the diode matters because higher capacitances are slower to react to fast transients?